# Git: how to specify a different user to fetch?

Tags: git

I login to one computer as userA.

```
$ git remote -v 
origin      git:/git/repo/code.git (fetch)
origin      git:/git/repo/code.git (push)
```

When I do "git fetch origin", it asks for password of userA.

Is it possible to fetch as userB on the git server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acording to "Credential Contexts" in [gitcredentials docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html) you can add you your git config file:

```
[credential "git:/git/repo/code.git"]
  username = userB
```

and that will do the tick.

Other way to achive want you want is changing your remotes:

```
git config remote.origin.url https://userB:password@example.com/repo.git
```

but you need to have an http url for your repository.

Comment: I couldn't get "credential" to work, but you remind me to change config file. Thanks.

Comment: please consider voting up my answer if it was helpful. that's the way SO works ;)